# If X is complete then $\bar A$ is compact iff $A$ is totally bounded.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. If X is complete then $\bar A$ is compact iff $A$ is totally bounded.

I have done the part that $A$ is totally bounded implies  $\bar A$ is compact. But how to do the other part? Help Needed!

Comment: Choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $B(x,\epsilon)$ be an open cover of $\bar{A}$.

Comment: then what to do.. can you please explain more

Comment: then you read again the definitions of compactness and total boundedness and you realize that you are done.

Comment: Compactness says something about the above open cover.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\overline{A}$ is compact.

Observe that for each $\epsilon>0$, $\overline{A}\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{x\in A}B(x,\epsilon) $. Hence $\left( B(x,\epsilon)\right)_{x\in A} $is an open covering of $\overline{A}$. Since $\overline{A}$ is compact $\left( B(x,\epsilon)\right)_{x\in A} $ has a finite sub covering  $\left( B(x_{i},\epsilon)\right)_{i=1}^n $. Clearly $\left( B(x_{i},\epsilon)\right)_{i=1}^n $ covers $A$. Therefore for each $\epsilon>0$, there exist $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_1,x_2,...,x_n\in A$ and $A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB(x_{i},\epsilon)$. That is $A$ is totally bounded.